# In-app purchase for ios6

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, ios6

I've noticed today that in-App purchases doesn't work for ios6. I didn't change any line of the code and my in-app purchase works on ios 5.1 or older version but not for ios6.
What's happening? Is this fault of my code? Should I change code for ios6?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing in simulator?

Comment: have you read the Apple's documentation?

Comment: @rocky no i'm testing it on a device.

Comment: @holex no i haven't :( can you link it please?

Comment: here is the link for the **[In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267)**, I haven't seen any relevant changes.